# Stellar Core from Source vs. Stellar Core from Container

Tags: stellar-core, docker

Are there any vulnerabilities or security considerations I should be aware of with running Stellar Core from source as opposed to running it from the Docker Container?

Answer (score 1):

If you're sticking to [stable releases](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/releases), it should be the same thing.